# row data gateway return value

Tags: design-patterns, poeaa

Recently, I read about the row data gateway pattern in the poeaa.

My question is, what is the return value by the row data gateway pattern. Is it the gateway object itself? if so, doesn't this add a dependency between DAL and BLL?

I mean, like in the repository pattern, we have a relation: DAL -> BLL, for example:

```
class personrepository
{
   public model.person getpersonby(id) {...}
}
```

but in the gateway, the relation is like this: BLL -> DAL, for example:

```
//organize by transaction script
class personservice
{
   public static void dosomethingwith(persongateway) {...}
}
```

am I misunderstanding something?